# How can I maintain gridview page index while navigation from the form?

Tags: asp.net

How can I maintain gridview page index while navigating away from the form and getting back by either the browser's back button or custom navigation button?

Answer (score 1):

Save the current index in Session or other kind of state source (db, or file system), which crosses the bounds of single form (not a ViewState for sure).

I guess Session is the best for you.